# Magnet links and CakePHP's Html Helper

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, html-helper

I want to be able to create a magnet link using CakePHP's Html Helper. How would I go about doing that?

I've already tried something like:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link($name, 'magnet:.....');
?>
```

My point: CakePHP sees anything that does not start with 'http://' as a relative URL. At least that's what the manual states.

Of course I could go and hammer (filter) out the 'http://' after having put it there before the 'magnet'-part.

But is there some (better) way for this without resorting to non-CakePHP-assisted HTML code?

Comment: Hi, what version of CakePHP are you using? I just tried in 1.3 `echo $this->Html->link('Example', 'magnet://');` and ouput was `<a href="magnet://">Example</a>` and after clicking link firefox ask me with what aplication i want associated it.

Comment: As long as the URL contains `://` it should be returned as-is. http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/router/#l-856

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I just checked proper magnet URI scheme i thought that `://` is part of it.

Comment: µTorrent does not accept a magnet-URL that starts with 'magnet://'. It needs just 'magnet:'. At least, I checked just now and it does not accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forcing something that you don't need to do. The largest draw to using Cake's $html->url() function is to quickly and easily generate dynamic urls that work with Cake's routing. That has little to do with magnet urls.  I'd say just go old-school here.

```
<a href='magnet:<?php echo $magnet_url; ?>'>Magnet Link</a>
```